# Cannot record audio using screen recording on Google Meet

Tags: google-meet

I am using screen recording to record Google Meet on phone. Unfortunately, the recording cannot record audio. It shows an error that the microphone is on used.

Any way to record Google Meet on phone? I am not the organizer.

Comment: Maybe the screen recorder app has settings for sound? Try selecting system if it is available (guess, I haven't tried)// or put it in speaker mode to record (provided it does not disturb others)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Due to privacy concerns, while screen-recording, Google has put up restrictions to record audio in apps such as Google Meet, Google Assistant,etc